# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, loops, foreach, php-5.6

I'm trying to create file upload systems its giving foreach() invalid argument supplied

```
if(isset($_POST['prd_submit'])){
// Define Input Variables
    $name = user_input($_POST['prd_name']);
    $detail =  user_input($_POST['prd_detail']);
    $image = $_POST['prd_image'];
    $buy_link = user_input($_POST['prd_link']);
    $price = user_input($_POST['prd_price']);
    $category = $_POST['prd_category'];
    $country = $_POST['prd_country'];
    // Control Error Inputs
    if(empty($name)){
        $name_err = "Name is missing";
    }
    if(empty($detail)){
        $detail_err = "Detail is missing";
    }
    if(empty($image)){
        $image_err = "Image is missing";
    }else{
    $File = $image;
    $OutFiles = array();
        foreach($File as $Index=>$Items){
            foreach($Items as $Key=>$Item){
                $OutFiles[$Key][$Index] = $Item;
            }
        }
    print_r($OutFiles);
    die();
```

Please help how i can fix it. Because i couldn't get any idea what thing is supplying wrong

Comment: share `print_r($_POST);`  value?

Comment: what gives `var_dump($image);` ?

Comment: Your $File needs to be an array ? Have you tried checking the value what you are getting in $File ?

Comment: Should probably be `$_FILES['prd_image']` instead of `$_POST['prd_image']`

Comment: `array (size=5)
  0 => string 'post1.png' (length=9)
  1 => string 'post2.png' (length=9)
  2 => string 'post3.png' (length=9)
  3 => string 'post4.png' (length=9)
  4 => string 'post5.png' (length=9)` var_dump value

Comment: i have given `$_FILES` now it's giving Undefined `prd_image` HTML INPUT `<input type="file" name="prd_image[]" multiple/>`

Comment: Have you add the enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't user $_POST for getting file data, use $_FILES

```
$image = $_FILES['prd_image'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The element `$image = $_POST['prd_image'];` needs to be an array of arrays.

Do a `var_dump($image)` just before your `foreach` statement and see whether it is an array as expected.

Furthermore, which `foreach` gives you the error?